# Inner products on the Dual Space exercise

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, dual-spaces

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over the field $K$, with a non-degenerate scalar product. Let $W$ be a subspace. Show that $W^{\perp\perp}=W$.
>   Show that the same conclusion as in the preceding exercise is valid if by $W^{\perp}$ we mean the orthogonal complement of $W$ in the dual space $V^*$.

I am self-studying, and questions and doubts seem to be exponentially increasing while I am going through the functionals.

**Questions**:

**1**) Does $W$ lie in the dual space?

**2**) How can I deal with ortoghonality in the dual space? What about its inner product?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Let $W$ be a subspace" (of $V$ or $V^*$)?

Comment: I dont have an answer to 2), but surely this is explained in the book you are reading. I can ask what book is? This will be essential to ask these questions properly. In 1) I assume that $W$ is a subspace of $V$ in first place. After it make the same question supposing that $W$ is a subpsace of $V^*$.

Comment: @Masacroso                   Serge Lang Linear Algebra

Answer (score 1):

You have a perfect pairing $$V^\ast \times V \ni (f,v)\mapsto f(v) \in \Bbb K$$that works like a inner product. In this light, the annihilator of a subspace is precisely the orthogonal complement.

Bear the relevant definitions in mind: $W^\perp = \{x \in V \mid \langle x,y\rangle = 0,\, \forall\,y \in W  \}$ is a subspace of $V$, while ${\rm Ann}(W) \equiv W^0 = \{ f \in V^\ast \mid f\big|_W = 0 \}$ is a subspace of $V^\ast$. They live in different worlds.

With this in mind, $W^{\perp\perp}$ is again a subspace of $V$, and so it makes sense to wonder if $W^{\perp\perp}$ is equal to $W$. On the other hand, the double annihilator $W^{00}$ is a subspace of $V^{\ast\ast}$, so you must understand the abuse of notation: what the exercise wants you to prove is that $J[W] = W^{00}$, where $J$ is the natural map from $V$ to $V^{\ast \ast}$ (which you should know what it is, since you got this far).

Alternatively, if $X \subseteq V^\ast$ is a subspace, you can think of $X_0 = \{ v \in V \mid f(v) = 0,\,\forall\,f \in X \}$. With this notion, you can prove that $W^0_{\,\,\,0} = W$, your pick.

Comment: Why is $W^{00}$ a subspace of $V^{**}$?

Comment: Write the definition $W^{00} =\{\cdots\} $, it will become clear. I want *you* to have the "aha" moment :P

Comment: $W^{00}=\{f\in V^{**}:f(v)\neq 0\}$?

Comment: No. Where does $W^0$ come in there? Think a bit.

Comment: Sorry but I am not getting it.

Comment: Come on, look at the definition. If $W \subseteq V$, then $W^0 = \{f \in V^\ast \mid f\big|_W = 0\}$. Now we have $W^0 \subseteq V^\ast$. So in this setting, $W^{00} = \{ \Phi \in V^{\ast\ast} \mid \Phi\big|_{W^0} =0\}$.

Comment: Can I directly state $W^{00} = \{ \Phi \in V^{\ast\ast} \mid \Phi\big|_{W^0} =0\}=W^{0}$ or do I need to include a few more steps. Because I am not seeing how?

Comment: No. Read my initial answer again: $W^{00}$ and $W^0$ are subspaces of different spaces, they're not comparable.

Comment: Could you finish the proof please? I am still getting the hang on the double dual spaces, and I want to see more of their workings, to actually develop intuitions about them. Thanks for the answers insofar!

Comment: I am not finding the answer. Could you please complete the proof?